# microphone access denied even after granting access to website in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, microphone

So i wrote a code for a website that converts speech to text which worked perfectly when tested in local host but then today i uploaded it to the internet and when i run the website the microphone access is always denied i have granted access for it again and again but it still doesn't allow the microphone to start listening. I have tried it in different devices and browsers but the same thing happens. Any idea what the problem is? Maybe i need and extra line of code to grant access to microphone?

Comment: There should be no difference wether having the code local or remote. Does your local version still work? Try re uploading your local code.

Comment: Have you tried using a private or incognito window to attempt to reproduce the issue locally? Have you checked browser permission settings locally? Maybe there is less security on your local machine?

Comment: From which protocol is your page served? `http://` or `https://`? Also, can you show the request you make? You talk about STT, was it from a `recognition.start();`?

Comment: currently it on http:// but i just bought an ssl. does that make a difference>?